# C# GDI Game Loop (FPS Counter)

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi, game-loop

I'm currently making a 2D Game Engine using C#, GDI and have setup a simple frame cap. The game can only render 60fps.

As far as I know there's no issue with the code however, I would just like a cleaner way of rendering 60fps and no more.

Here's my code, any help would be great

```
        public void Run()
    {
        window.Show();
        window.Focus();

        Initialize();

        isRunning = true;
        canRender = true;

        timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        // the amount of milliseconds needed to pass before rendering next frame
        double frameCapCounter = 16.666666;

        while (isRunning)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();

            if (window.Focused)
            {
                if (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds >= frameCapCounter)
                {
                    canRender = true;
                    frames += 1; // update amount of frames
                    frameCapCounter += 16.666666; // increment counter
                }
                else
                {
                    canRender = false;
                }

                // this is used to check if a second has passed, and if so
                // we set the fps variable to the amount of frames rendered
                // and reset all variables.
                if (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 1000)
                {
                    fps = frames;
                    frames = 0;
                    frameCapCounter = 0;
                    timer.Restart();
                }

                Update();
                LateUpdate();

                if (canRender)
                    Render();
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The guys from SlimDX (https://slimdx.org/docs/html/Managed_Message_Loop.htm) used this instead of `Application.DoEvents()`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmiller/2005/05/05/my-last-post-on-render-loops-hopefully/

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, instead of keeping track of time elapsed, frames rendered, etc. etc., you could simply sleep the number of milliseconds to cap your FPS, example:

```
public void Run()
{
    window.Show();
    window.Focus();

    Initialize();

    isRunning = true;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        if (window.Focused)
        {
            Update();
            LateUpdate();
            Render();
            Thread.Sleep(16); // hard cap
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this, however, is that up to the sleep, the rest of that code could take longer than 16 milliseconds; to this, you could do some performance measurements and do something like 10ms instead.

Another way, keeping a timer active would be something like the following:

```
public void Run()
{
    window.Show();
    window.Focus();

    Initialize();

    isRunning = true;

    long limit = 1000 / 60;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        if (window.Focused)
        {
            timer.Restart();
            Update();
            LateUpdate();
            Render();
            while (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < limit) {
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids the "hard" cap while also taking into consideration the fact that all code up to the sleep could take longer than 16ms, thus not enter the "wait" loop if the requisite time has passed.

Also, a few notes to consider with your posted code:

First, if you are not using any Windows Form elements (like a `PictureBox`, `Button`, `TextBox`, etc.), and instead are drawing all elements your self (e.g. calling something like `Graphics.DrawLine`, etc.), you do not need to call [`Application.DoEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); doing so causes the calling thread to wait until all other Windows Forms messages have been processed, thus slowing down the render loop. If you do indeed need to call `Application.DoEvents` it would be better to do it after your `Render()`, so as to include that function call time in your frame limit.

Lastly, when specifying a [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of anything less than [approximately 20 milliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a non-real-time Windows systems, chances are that the `Sleep` will actually sleep for longer due to the time slice dedicated to a thread on a Windows system. So the `Thread.Sleep(1)` *might* sleep for 1 millisecond, **OR** it might sleep for 6 milliseconds; and if the time cap is already at 14 milliseconds, a 6 millisecond sleep would put your total time upwards of 20 milliseconds, thus slowing your frame rate.

Specifying a sleep of `0` milliseconds relinquishes the remainder of the time slice for the calling thread to another thread of equal priority that is ready to run; if no other threads are ready, then the calling thread continues (so 0-1 milliseconds of wait, vs 6+). You could also use [`Thread.Yield`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but that acts much different than `Sleep` at the kernel level.

Hope that can help.